# Are direct attach fibre NICs compatible with 10GBASE-SR/SW 400m multimode fiber cabling?

Tags: server, network-adapter

I have around 100 Finisar FTLX8574D3BCL transceivers I need test so I'm looking for a pair of PCIE 8x cards.
I see a lot of DA cards (example: Intel 94F2046 X520-DA2) for sale on ebay but I'm not looking to test direct attach cables. Are 10Gb DA cards compatible with 10GBASE-SR/SW 400m multimode cabling or are they used for storage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DA cabling is copper. I'm going to assume these are not going to work with fiber transceivers.